# Finding a path $p_n$ in a hyperbolic, 1-ended group joining points that stays within $B(e,n+2\delta+2)-B(e,n)$ except at endpoints

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Let $G = \langle S \rangle$ be a finitely generated, 1-ended $\delta$-hyperbolic group, let $\Gamma$ be its Cayley graph.

I want to show that for any $n$, there are points $a_n$, $b_n$ such that $d(a_n, b_n) = 2n$, $d(a_n, e) = d(b_n, e) = n$, and there is a path $p$ joining $a_n$, $b_n$ which intersects $B(e,n)$ only at $a_n$ and $b_n$, and is contained in the closed ball $B(e, n+2\delta+2)$.

My ideas so far:

$G$ is 1 ended, so if we remove the compact $B(e,n-1)$, we get an unbounded connected component. There certainly exist points $a \in G$ such that $d(e,a) = n$, since $G$ is an infinite, locally finite graph. But my problem is: what if there is only 1 point at distance $n$ from $e$? Why doesn't this case arise?

Maybe this is something to do with growth functions, since we are looking for the change in number of elements from $|B(n-1)|$ to $|B(n)|$ to be bigger than 1.

Once we have $a_n$ and $b_n$ with the distances desired, I don't see exactly why there is a path that fits within the bounds given either. Maybe if we take a minimal length path from $a_n$ to $b_n$ that doesn't intersect $B(e,n)$ (this certainly exists since you can go away from $e$ from both $a_n$, $b_n$, and you are still connected, right?), call it $p$, this works. It has some length $\geq 2n$. We know the path from $a_n$ to $e$ to $b_n$ is geodesic (by the distances required earlier), call this $q$. I think that the paths $p$ and $q$ must be somewhat close ($p$ seems like a quasigeodesic, since we took minimal length, but this is probably not true), and this probably gives the last result.

I really have little intuition for hyperbolic groups, the only 1 ended finitely generated group I really have a grasp on is $\mathbb{Z}^2$, which is not hyperbolic, so my intuition fails me most of the time. Help appreciated.

Comment: This isn't quite an answer, but (infinite) hyperbolic groups always have lots of free subgroups, so if there were $g,h \in G$ such that $\langle g,h\rangle$ is free, and $d_S(g^k,e) = d_S(h^\ell,e) = n$, but there were only one group element at distance $n$, we would be forced to have $g^k = h^\ell$, a contradiction.

Comment: Any group acting properly and cocompactly by isometries on $\mathbb{H}^2$ or $\mathbb{H}^3$ will be one-ended, so maybe you might find the fundamental group of a closed surface of genus $g \ge 2$ a helpful intuition?

Comment: Hint: Use first find a bi-infinite geodesic $c$ passing through $e$. Then use the nearest-point projection (to $B$) of a path connecting points $c(-n-10\delta-10, n+10\delta+10)$ outside of $B=B(n+2\delta+2)$.